# Firebase auth fetches Deleted user

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
 await _auth.currentUser()
```

This line fetches deleted users.

In my app, I tested deleting a user from the firebase console and then I ran this:

```
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
      print('linking account ${currentUser.uid}');
      firebaseUser = await _auth.linkWithCredential(credential);
    } else {
      firebaseUser = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
```

Although the user has been deleted, ( I deleted them all to make sure that it has been actually deleted, I still get the output:

```
 linking account ua1gzDXZRmTZI0gxGeu36iF5ETO2
```

Which triggers an error on the next line:

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7016): PlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your JWT token is still valid, but your refresh token not. Important do remember that JWT is stateless, and the access token revocation has to be done intrinsically for the deleted user.

In the section [Detect ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions)
 you can find how to set up Firebase Rules that check for token revocation

Hope it helps